# How to redirect wpmu Directory "edit listing" button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, forms

I am using a WordPress plugin that provides a front end editor to create a custom post type (directory). When I create a new directory listing the page redirects back to the /listings/my-listings/, however when I edit an existing listing and click the save button it dose not redirect. The page page instead refreshes and adds a # to the end of the URL (/listings/edit-listing/#). Could anyone look at this and help me to tweak the php or provide a javascript/jquery to redirect me back to the /listings/my-listings/?

I believe it has something to do with the .submit class at the bottom of the code...

Code:

```
<?php
get_header(); 
/**
* The template for displaying the Add/edit listing page.
* You can override this file in your active theme.
*
* @license GNU General Public License (Version 2 - GPLv2) {@link 
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html}
*/

global $wp_query, $wp_taxonomies, $post, $post_ID, $CustomPress_Core, 
$Directory_Core;
$listing_data   = '';
$selected_cats  = '';
$error = get_query_var('dr_error');
$post_statuses = get_post_statuses(); // get the wp post status list
$options = $Directory_Core->get_options('general');

$allowed_statuses = $Directory_Core->get_options('general'); // Get the ones we allow
$allowed_statuses['moderation'] = (empty($allowed_statuses['moderation']) ) ? array('publish' => 1,    'draft'=> 1 ) : $allowed_statuses['moderation']; // Get the ones we allow
$allowed_statuses = array_reverse(array_intersect_key($post_statuses,         $allowed_statuses['moderation']) ); //return the reduced list

//Are we adding a Listing?
if (is_page($Directory_Core->add_listing_page_id)) {
    //Make an auto-draft so we have a post id to connect attachemnts to. Set global $post_ID so media editor can hook up. Watch the case
    $post_ID = wp_insert_post( array( 'post_title' => __( 'Auto Draft' ), 'post_type' => $Directory_Core->post_type, 'post_status' => 'auto-draft' ) );
    $listing_data = get_post($post_ID, ARRAY_A );
    $listing_data['post_title'] = ''; //Have to have a title to insert the auto-save but we don't want it as final.
    $editing = false;
}

//Or are we editing a listing?
if(is_page($Directory_Core->edit_listing_page_id)){
    $listing_data = get_post(  $_REQUEST['post_id'], ARRAY_A );
    $post_ID = $listing_data['ID'];
    $editing = true;
}
$post = get_post($post_ID);

if ( isset( $_POST['listing_data'] ) ) $listing_data =    $_POST['listing_data'];

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/template.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php');

$editor_settings =   array(
'wpautop' => true, // use wpautop?
'media_buttons' => true, // show insert/upload button(s)
'textarea_name' => 'listing_data[post_content]', // set the textarea name to something different, square brackets [] can be used here
'textarea_rows' => 10, //get_option('default_post_edit_rows', 10), // rows="..."
'tabindex' => '',
'editor_css' => '', // intended for extra styles for both visual and HTML editors buttons, needs to include the <style> tags, can use "scoped".
'editor_class' => 'required', // add extra class(es) to the editor textarea
'teeny' => false, // output the minimal editor config used in Press This
'dfw' => false, // replace the default fullscreen with DFW (needs specific css)
'tinymce' => true, // load TinyMCE, can be used to pass settings directly to TinyMCE using an array()
'quicktags' => true // load Quicktags, can be used to pass settings directly to Quicktags using an array()
);

$listing_content = (empty( $listing_data['post_content'] ) ) ? '' :    $listing_data['post_content'];

wp_enqueue_script('set-post-thumbnail');
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $Directory_Core->plugin_url . 'ui-front/js/jquery.tagsinput.min.js'; ?>" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $Directory_Core->plugin_url . 'ui-front/js/media-post.js'; ?>" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $Directory_Core->plugin_url . 'ui-front/js/ui-front.js'; ?>" >
</script>

<?php if ( !empty( $error ) ): ?>
<br /><div class="error"><?php echo $error . '<br />'; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="dr_update_form">

    <form class="standard-form base" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="dr_update_form" >
        <input type="hidden" id="post_ID" name="listing_data[ID]" value="<?php echo ( isset( $listing_data['ID'] ) ) ? $listing_data['ID'] : ''; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo ( isset( $listing_data['ID'] ) ) ? $listing_data['ID'] : ''; ?>" />

        <?php if(post_type_supports('directory_listing','title') ): ?>
        <div class="editfield">
            <label for="title"><?php _e( '<strong>Agent Name:</strong>', $Directory_Core->text_domain ); ?></label>
            <input class="required" type="text" id="title" name="listing_data[post_title]" value="<?php echo ( isset( $listing_data['post_title'] ) ) ? esc_attr($listing_data['post_title']) : ''; ?>" />
            <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter agents name here.', $Directory_Core->text_domain ); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
<!-- Start Add Featured Image / Agent Headshot-->
        <?php if(post_type_supports('directory_listing','thumbnail') && current_theme_supports('post-thumbnails') ): ?>
        <div class="editfield">
            <div><strong>Agent Headshot:</strong></div>
            <?php if(empty($options['media_manager']) ): ?>

            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?><br />
            <script type="text/javascript">js_translate.image_chosen = '<?php _e("Feature Image Chosen", $Directory_Core->text_domain); ?>';</script>
            <span class="upload-button">

                <?php $class = ( empty($options['field_image_req']) && !has_post_thumbnail() ) ? 'required' : ''; ?>

                <input type="file" name="feature_image" size="1" id="image" class="<?php echo $class; ?>" />
                <button type="button" class="button"><?php _e('Add Agent Headshot', $Directory_Core->text_domain); ?></button>
            </span>
            <br />

            <?php else: ?>

            <div id="postimagediv">
                <div class="inside">
                    <?php
                    $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta( $post_ID, '_thumbnail_id', true );
                    echo _wp_post_thumbnail_html($thumbnail_id, $post_ID);
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
<!-- End Add Featured Image / Agent Headshot-->
<!-- Start Taxonimy, Category and custom All Services-->
        <?php
        //get related hierarchical taxonomies
        $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('directory_listing', 'objects');
        $taxonomies = empty($taxonomies) ? array() : $taxonomies;

        //Loop through the taxonomies that apply
        foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy):
        if( ! $taxonomy->hierarchical) continue;
        $tax_name = $taxonomy->name;
        $labels = $taxonomy->labels;
        //Get this Taxonomies terms
        $selected_cats = array_values( wp_get_post_terms($listing_data['ID'], $tax_name, array('fields' => 'ids') ) );


        ?>

        <div id="taxonomy-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>" class="dr_taxonomydiv">
            <label><?php echo $labels->all_items; ?></label>

            <div id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>_all" class="dr_tax_panel">
                <?php
                $name = ( $tax_name == 'category' ) ? 'post_category' : 'tax_input[' . $tax_name . ']';
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='{$name}[]' value='0' />";          // Allows for an empty term set to be sent. 0 is an invalid Term ID and will be ignored by empty() checks.
            ?>
                <ul id="<?php echo $tax_name; ?>_checklist" class="list:<?php echo $labels->name; ?> categorychecklist form-no-clear">
                    <?php wp_terms_checklist( 0, array( 'taxonomy' => $tax_name, 'selected_cats' => $selected_cats, 'checked_ontop' => false ) ) ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
<!-- End Taxonimy, Category and custom All Services-->
        <div class="clear"><br /></div>
<!-- Start Custom Press / Custom Fields-->
        <?php if ( isset( $CustomPress_Core ) ) : ?>
            <?php echo do_shortcode('[custom_fields_input style="editfield"]'); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( !empty( $error ) ): ?>
        <br /><div class="error"><?php echo $error . '<br />'; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
<!-- End Custom Press / Custom Fields-->
<!-- Start Select as Draft/Pyblic-->
        <div class="editfield" >
            <label for="title"><?php _e( 'Status', $Directory_Core->text_domain ); ?></label>
            <div id="status-box">
                <select name="listing_data[post_status]" id="listing_data[post_status]">
                    <?php
                foreach($allowed_statuses as $key => $value): ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php selected( ! empty($listing_data['post_status'] ) && $key == $listing_data['post_status'] ); ?> ><?php echo $value; ?></option>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Please select a status for your listing. If you select your listing status as “Published” your listing will be made live and available for the public to view. If you select your listing status as “Draft” your listing will not be visible to the public and you can come back later to finish/publish.', $Directory_Core->text_domain ); ?></p>
        </div>
<!-- End Select as Draft/Pyblic-->
        <div class="submit">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'verify' ); ?>
            <input type="submit" value="<?php _e( 'Save Changes', $Directory_Core->text_domain ); ?>" name="update_listing">

            <input type="button" value="<?php _e( 'Cancel', $Directory_Core->text_domain ); ?>" onclick="location.href='<?php echo get_permalink($Directory_Core->my_listings_page_id); ?>'">
        </div>
        <?php //echo do_shortcode('[ct_validate]') ; ?>
    </form>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I assume you mean Javascript rather than Java?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that....

Comment: Can anyone help out with this one???? Thanks...

Comment: give us the plugin name.

Comment: WPMUDEV Directory  https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wordpress-directory/

Answer (score -1):

Since your PHP is inside your code, you do not need the action attribute in your `<form>` tag. take `action="#"` out of the form tag and you should be good to go.

Right here:

```
<form class="standard-form base" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="dr_update_form" >
```

The action attribute is to send the data to another `url` and is why you get the `#` at the end of the current url.

something like this?

```
<input id="myButton" type="submit" value="<?php _e( 'Save Changes', $Directory_Core->text_domain ); ?>" name="update_listing">

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "www.yoursite.com/listings/edit-listing/";
    };
</script>
```

Comment: If the action was removed, what would cause the page to redirect to `/listings/my-listings/` if someone fills out the form on `/listings/edit-listing/`?

Comment: Hi Adam, That did not work. Now when I try to click into the edit listing page I get redirected to view listing... Any other thoughts? Thanks, William

Comment: @mevius the OP's question says "The page page instead refreshes and adds a # to the end of the URL (/listings/edit-listing/#)" So it adds a # to the end not the whole url. Go troll some where else.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I'm not trolling. The OP says that submitting the form adds a `#` to the end of the URL **AND** that he/she wants to redirect to `/listings/my-listings/` after a form submission (from `/listings/edit-listing/`). Your answer takes care of getting rid of the `#`, but does nothing else. Work on the reading comprehension.

Comment: Yeah ok, troll on! You should answer it then.

Comment: I honestly don't understand how it's trolling (and it definitely didn't warrant you down-voting a question of mine because you were upset). I just asked a simple question. As shown by the OP's response, your answer doesn't fit the bill. Full disclosure: I answered the question exactly how you did (before you did), but deleted it because it is obviously missing the second component. In order to answer the OP's question, we would need more info about the form processing process.

Comment: What other info do you need? I would be happy to provide. :-)

Comment: @William where do you want the page to be redirected to?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith This php page controls adding a new listing and editing an existing listing. When I add a new listing the page redirects to /listings/my-listings/ but when I'm editing an existing listing it dose not (refreshes and adds a # to the end of the URL (/listings/edit-listing/#)). I would like both add listing and edit listing to redirect to the /listings/my-listings/ page when the user clicks "Save Changes" at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @William I have looked at this again and still cannot see the issue, what is in post.php?

Comment: I know for sure the answer dose not lie in post.php. I don't want to have to edit the core WP files. Any other suggestions? is there a JavaScript i could use to redirect something inside of <div class="submit">? Thanks

Comment: Hi @AdamBuchananSmith this new solution did not work either. The page is still refreshing and adding the # to the end of the url... Any other thoughts? Thanks